# Vb.net Multiplying textbox with time and combo box value

Tags: vb.net

I have a masked textbox with time value ("hh:mm" the duration the task wil take) and a combo box with 1-10.

How do I mutilply the masked textbox with the combo box to get the total dutation it would take in "hh:mm.

I have txttime1 as the first textbox that holds the time. (masked textbox)

Cmb1 with 1-10, this indicates how many times the txttime1 must be multiplied.

Txtdura1 as the answer to the multiplication. Basically the total duration of the event.

Any direction would be great.

Comment: What's the datatype you're getting from the masked textbox?

Comment: it is a DateTime

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a bit more succinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string from the textbox to a TimeSpan. Then change to TotalMinutes which is a Double so you can perform multiplication. Take the result of the multiplication and change it to a TimeSpan .FromMinutes. You can then format the result in various ways.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact(TextBox2.Text, "h\:m", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    Dim dblTotalMinutes As Double = ts.TotalMinutes
    Dim Multiplier As Integer = CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    Dim MultipliedMinutes As Double = dblTotalMinutes * Multiplier
    Dim MultipliedTimeSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(MultipliedMinutes)
    'For days:hours:minutes
    TextBox3.Text = MultipliedTimeSpan.ToString("d\:hh\:mm")
    'Total Hours as double
    TextBox4.Text = MultipliedTimeSpan.TotalHours.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the hours and minutes apart from each other, create a `TimeSpan` object and multiply that by the factor from the ComboBox:

```
Dim duration As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(txttime1.Text)
Txtdura1 = duration.Multiply(Integer.Parse(Cmb1.Text)).ToString("hh\:mm")
```

Relevant documentation:

- [`TimeSpan.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netcore-2.2)
- [`TimeSpan.Multiply()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.multiply?view=netcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2)
- [`TimeSpan.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: I believe the TimeSpan.Multiply is only available in .net core.

Comment: @Mary OP has `.net` tagged, I'd assume this method would be available.